# Why this jquery variable is not being reset?

Tags: jquery, variables, setinterval

I am using setinterval in which eachtime ajax data is set with the var pro.
BUt the data is not being set  with the pro variable

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


    setInterval(moving_header, 3000);
});
function moving_header() {

    var pro = '1';


    $.post('send.php', { option:'moving_header', pro:pro}, function (data) {
        alert(data);

        pro = data;


    });


}
```

Suppose  the data=2 but  pro=1 is not set being set as the pro=2.Plz help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare pro outside `moving_header` so that is is not initialized each time moving_header is call by `setInterval`

```
 var pro = '1';
 function moving_header() {      
    $.post('send.php', { option:'moving_header', pro:pro}, function (data) {
        alert(data);    
        pro = data;        
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare outside, Second you can remove `''` quotes too:

```
var pro = 1;
function moving_header() {
  $.post('send.php', { option:'moving_header', pro:pro}, function (data) {
    alert(data);
    pro = data;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure ajax call finish in 3 seconds ? second request can be start while the first is continue.